# Updating Entity Designer DDL Script to generate database for SQL Server 2019

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I have an old ASP.NET Web app that is using ASP.NET. 4.5 and I want to run it in a Docker container. To do that I need to update the database generation script in EF6. I used a Model First Approach, but when generating the Entity Designer DDL script, it says that the script is only for up to MS SQL Server 2008. I need it to be compatible with 2017 or 2019 as those are the only ones that I can run in a Docker container.

I've updated to EF6 and remade the Context.tt and .tt files but the DDL Script hasn't updated.

```
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: 06/01/2019 13:55:02
-- Generated from EDMX file: C:\Users
```

I need the DDL Script to work for SQL Server 2017 or 2019.

Comment: Is says 2012 and Azure. Did you try it with 2017 and 2019?

Comment: @ErikEJ I have not tried running a 2017 Docker MS SQL Container and connecting to it. Since the generated script only includes up to 2012, I have thought it would not work with a 2017 container.

Comment: It will work with 2017!

Comment: Ok, I will try it then. Thank you @ErikEJ

Answer (score 0):

Given that SQL Server is almost 100% backwards compatible, this script will work fine on SQL Server 2017 and 2019